# Optimization of creating pandas dataframe from recordset

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy

I was thinking that created very simple code:

```
def recordset_2_list(cursor):
    data = []
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        data.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
    return data
```

However, I got crash (memory issue) here almost every time. `Row Count` = 530002 records

How can it be optimized?

```
engine = create_engine(CONN_STR, echo=True)
connection = engine.raw_connection()
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.callproc("sp_create_training_data", [id])
    return list_2_dataframe(recordset_2_list(cursor))


def list_2_dataframe(data):
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data.columns = map(str.upper, data.columns)
    return data
```

**Update 1:** Approach with below code, also return `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

```
df = pd.read_sql(sa.text('SELECT * FROM sp_create_training_data(:arg1'),
    engine, params={'arg1': id})
return df
```

**Update 2:** it works, any ideas how can it be speed up yet?

```
print 'Start loading data ...'
try:
    engine = create_engine(CONN_STR, echo=True)
    df = pd.read_sql(sa.text('SELECT * FROM sp_create_training_data(:arg1)'),
        engine, params={'arg1': id}, chunksize=5000)
    print "Executed Store Proc"
    lst = []
    for chun in df:
        lst.append(chun)
    print "Prepared chunks"
    df_big = pd.concat(lst)
    return df_big
except Exception, err:
    print err.message
    return None
```

Answer (score 2):

For loading data from databases use [pandas.read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)

Comment: If you will use chunksize? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/io.html#querying

Comment: Yes, it works. thanks! Any ideas about optimization mentioned in `Update 2`

Comment: It seems to me that there is a bug in sqlalchemy (or other) because I loaded bigger datasets in pandas without any problem.